# Latex error, font not found

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I'm trying to use the [QT Deuce font](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/qtdeuce/) which should be installed (apt install texlive-full, texlive-fonts recommended, texlive-fonts extra).

My file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{QTDeuce}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

I'm using lualatex and getting this error:

```
[...]
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc=; reason: "Font QTDeuce not found.".
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

! Package fontspec Error: The font "QTDeuce" cannot be found.
[...]
```

What do I miss?

Comment: looking at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/qualitype these were added in 2019, you are using apt so a system supplied texlive not the upstream texlive 2021 from tug, is your texlive new enough? (you coul dget the otf files direct from ctan from that link)

Comment: okay, I downloaded it manually and now it works. Thanks. But why is this not included in texlive-full and whats the terminal command to install all the missing fonts?

Comment: you didn't answer my question, a linux-supplied texlive might be texlive 2017 for example, that does not have files added in 2019. It all depends on the stability/update policy of the distribution you are using.

Comment: `tex --version` gives:
`Tex 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)`

Comment: OK so you have texlive 2019 but that's a couple of years old: it may not have these fonts which were added in 2019.  Your example runs without error in texlive 2021

Comment: okay, thanks alot